# python - calculate landmarks within distance from a latitude and longitude and append in loop

Tags: python

Given a 2d list of lats and longs and landmark features
how do I find those landmarks within say 10km of the user input current location lat long?
I then want to append these distances (stationDist) in a new 2d list (distanceList) as I go in a loop.

How do I write this in Python code? I have no idea!! Please help

```
import math

def main():
    DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111120.0
    latOne = 55.9669
    lonOne = 114.5967
    latTwo = 55.9622
    lonTwo = 114.5889
    coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
    alpha = 90 - latTwo
    beta  = 90 - latOne

    cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
    cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
    sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
    sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
    cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

    cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
    cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
    cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
    angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
    distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
    print '\nThe distance is: ', distance
```

Comment: How would you do it by hand?  Can't tell whether you're having problems with the math, or with Python.

Comment: Tim are you able to help?

Comment: Sorry, no, I'm just going to sleep now. Now that you added some initial attempt, I hope someone else picks it up!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to set it up. I have converted your meters to kilometers...

```
import math

def calcdist(p1,p2):
    latOne,lonOne=p1
    latTwo,lonTwo=p2
    DISTANCE_CONSTANT = 111.1200

    coLat = math.fabs(lonOne - lonTwo)
    alpha = 90 - latTwo
    beta  = 90 - latOne

    cosAlpha = math.cos(math.radians(alpha))
    cosBeta  = math.cos(math.radians(beta))
    sinAlpha = math.sin(math.radians(alpha))
    sinBeta  = math.sin(math.radians(beta))
    cosC     = math.cos(math.radians(coLat))

    cos_of_angle_a = (cosAlpha * cosBeta)
    cos_of_angle_b = (sinAlpha * sinBeta * cosC)
    cos_of_angle_c = cos_of_angle_a + cos_of_angle_b
    angle          = math.degrees(math.acos(cos_of_angle_c))
    distance       = angle * DISTANCE_CONSTANT
    return distance


ref = [36.0,-122.0]
names = ['close','far','kindaclose','ratherfar']
points = [[36.1,-122.0],[89.0,-123.0],[39.0,-122.0],[36.0,123.0]]

closelist=[]
threshold =12  #distance in km

for n,p in zip(names,points):   
    d = calcdist(ref,p)
    print '{} : {:.1f}'.format(n,d) 
    if d < threshold:  
       closelist.append([n,d])

print 'These are within {} km:'.format(threshold) , closelist
```

Output:

```
close : 11.1
far : 5889.4
kindaclose : 333.4
ratherfar : 9561.9
These are within 12 km: [['close',11.11200]]
```

Comment: Hi. thanks so much for a reply.  so do I still need the looping to ask each line in the list to calculate distance and then to append?

Comment: If you can edit your question to show an example of your data format, that would help. There are lots of ways to do it (dictionaries, if names are unique) and I just showed one.

Comment: In response to your question about the loop, as far as I can tell you would still need to loop.  You could do it as a one-liner with list comprehension, but it is still effectively looping. If there are lots of landmarks, most of which are not close to the reference, then you could pre-filter, so if the difference in degrees is more than a certain amount, don't calculate, but this is a pretty general solution. Find all distances, and while doing the calc, add those within range to another list. (You don't have to print each distance; that was just for demo).